# Apply DayNight theme to selected fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, themes, android-theme, theme-daynight

I have an app that consists of two fragments connected with `ViewPager`. The one on the left has custom background, the one on the right has basic light theme (white background, black text color, etc.). Now I want to implement `DayNight` theme to the right `fragment` (not to the one that has custom background). I tried to set `DayNight` to the main activity in AndroidManifest, but it changed the whole app - the left `fragment` and the right `fragment`.

Manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
```

Styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
   ...
</style>
```

Is it possible to set `DayNight` theme to only one of them? Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: Hi Tom11. This is the only question with the theme-daynight tag. You seem to know what it means, so can I ask you to define and explain? Otherwise the tag is so unhelpful.

Comment: Hi, DayNight theme is specific color theme that changes according to time of the day and battery status. It is applicable **not only** for Android applications.